# Coq stuck on proof for Theorem eqblist_true

Tags: coq

I'm stuck on this proof for the theorem eqblist_true. So far what I have is:

```
Theorem eqblist_true : forall l1 l2, 
   eqblist l1 l2 = true -> l1 = l2. 
Proof. 
   intros l1. induction l1 as [| l1']. 
   - intros l2 H. simpl in H. destruct l2 as [| l2']. 
     + reflexivity.
     + discriminate H. 
   - simpl. intros l2 H. destruct l2 as [|l2']. 
     + discriminate .
     + intros. intuition. assert (H1: l1' =? l2' = true). 
        assert (H2: eqblist l1 l2 = true).
```

and that's where I'm stuck. I know I can prove these asserts using `H`, `eqb_true`, `andb_true_r` and `andb_true_l` but I just don't know how.

Comment: What is the definition of `eqblist`? And which libraries are you importing? Please provide code that compiles, otherwise we can only guess what the context is.

Comment: For those interested in Proof Assistants, there is a new proposed SE site [ProofAssistants](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126242/proof-assistants?referrer=Njg4YTJmMjYwOTIxNjdkNGEyMmZkNzE0Y2M4YmFhOTY3OWVmNDUwNWM3ZmFlMjYwYTRiYzZiZWY1ODg5ZjdiMqfBIyhShuHO9QbGuJfVwOYRvfVgPfbJQrn2UOFTeOe-0)